# How can I redirect the output of a SQL query to a file?

Tags: perl

I need a little help in redirecting the output of a SQL query to a file. My code looks like this:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
    "select count(parameter2),
    parameter2 as file_type
    from KCRT_TABLE_ENTRIES where request_id = $mycrnum
    group by parameter2"
) or die "Can't prepare SQL statement: ", $dbh->errstr(), "\n";

$sth->execute > $mydir\\file_detail.txt
    or die "Can't execute SQL statement: ", $sth->errstr(), "\n";
```

Comment: I want the output of sql query to be saved on $mydir\\file_detail.txt.

Comment: If I remove the redirect option(> $mydir\\file_detail.txt) from the query, the script runs fine. I'm not able to redirect the value of $sth in a file.

Comment: Perl is not a shell; it doesn't have redirection operators.

Comment: Please let me know how to redirect the output then. I tried multiple options, and it doesn't seem working.

Comment: Did you look at the [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) docs? It kind of feels like you didn't, because there are actually complete examples in the docs that show how to select and fetch data.

Answer (score 5):

I've had to invent a lot of code as you don't show much of your program, but the program below gives you the rough idea

Once you've called `execute` you have to call one of the `fetch` methods to retrieve the data in whatever form is most useful to you. Here I've just asked for a reference to an array containing each row's data

Then it's simply a matter of opening the required file for output and printing the rows of data to it

I've removed the status checks on each DBI call and replaced it with the `RaiseError` flag which does the same thing automatically. I've also replaced the parameter `$mycrnum` in the SQL statement with a placeholder and passed its value to `execute`. That way DBI looks after any necessary quoting etc.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my ($dsn, $user, $pass);

my ($mycrnum, $mydir);

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass);
@{$dbh}{qw/ PrintError RaiseError /} = (0, 1);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT COUNT(parameter2),
    parameter2 AS file_type
    FROM kcrt_table_entries
    WHERE request_id = ?
    GROUP BY parameter2"
);

$sth->execute($mycrnum);

open my $fh, '>', "$mydir/file_detail.txt" or die $!;
select $fh;

while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref ) {
    printf "%5d %s\n", @$row;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After the execute, open the output file:

```
open my $of, ">", "$mydir\\file_detail.txt";
```

Then read each line (or row) in the results:

```
while ( @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
```

Printing the output to the opened file handle:

```
    print $of "@row\n";  # NO COMMA AFTER $of!
```

Close the while() loop:

```
}
```

Finally, close your opened file handle:

```
close $of;
```

Now your done.

Comment: I tried the option, but somehow the file did not get created. There were no error though.

Comment: If you do an `or die $!` after the `open`, you'll definitely see an error if something went wrong.

Comment: If I had to guess, the problem might be that you didn't $sth->execute.  I think Jim's code presupposes your $sth has been properly set up prior to this point.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
    select count(parameter2),
    parameter2 as file_type
    from KCRT_TABLE_ENTRIES where request_id = ?
    group by parameter2
}) or die "Can't prepare SQL statement: ", $dbh->errstr(), "\n";

$sth->execute($mycrnum);

open my $OUT, '>', "$mydir/file_detail.txt" or die;

while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
  print $OUT @row, "\n";   # or whatever...
}

close $OUT;

$sth->finish;
```

This is a little bit of overkill, since you are only reading a single value, but it at least demonstrates a boilerplate for getting it done for future queries.

If you ever have a guaranteed single row, you can do something like this:

```
my ($val1, $val1) = $dbh->selectrow_array(q{
    select foo, bar
});
```

Comment: I tried this option. There seems to be some syntax error. I'll check it tomorrow and try to get it work.

Comment: The syntax error is the unclosed brace for `q{}` in the first line.

Comment: Matt is right...  I didn't close the brace on the q{ }.  That's fixed.

Comment: I tried in similar way. After giving the die command, its showing error at open my $out(at line 5446).
Died at sblmaint.pl line 5446, <> line 3.

Comment: The file file_detail.txt need to be created at runtime. The directory $mydir is being created at runtime. Is this why the script is failing.

Comment: If I remove $mydir/, then the file is created. But in some other directory. When $mydir/ is included, then the file is not getting created. The error is<br>Can't create 'D:\SiebelAdmin\CR_Files\CR117365_20150821_0008<br>
/file_detail.txt' at sblmaint.pl line 5447, <> line 3.

Comment: It looks like you have a '<br>' in your $mydir variable...  and that literal folder name doesn't exist.  I think if you remove that or hard-code the path (for starters) it should work